# VBA Class Module: Runtime error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following class module `BlSecurity` in my Access database:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private tiendaRepo As ITiendaRepository

Public Sub Init(ptiendaRepo As ITiendaRepository)
    tiendaRepo = ptiendaRepo
End Sub

Public Sub Login(code As String)
    If tiendaRepo.CheckIfCodeExists(code) = "" Then
        Err.Raise Number:=CustomErrors.CenterCodeNotExisting
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set tiendaRepo = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is TiendaRepository code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Implements ITiendaRepository


Public Function ITiendaRepository_CheckIfCodeExists(ByVal code As String) As String
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, "CheckCode", "Not implemented"
    Exit Function
End Function
```

And this is the "interface" ITiendaRepository I'm implementing:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Public Function CheckIfCodeExists(ByVal code As String) As String
End Function
```

Then, inside a button handler:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim bl As blSecurity
    Set bl = New blSecurity
    bl.Init (New TiendaRepository)
    bl.Login (txtUsuario.Value)
End Sub
```

But when I click the button, I receive message:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

in line `bl.Init (New TiendaRepository)`

. What's wrong with it?

Comment: i think you need to create the object then pass it in, not pass in as new

Comment: @QHarr First code belongs to BlSecurity, I have updated my code

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I tried instantiating TiendaRepository in a new line before calling Init, but the error is thrown anyway :-(

Comment: Try removing the parentheses - use `bl.Init New TiendaRepository` and `bl.Login txtUsuario.Value`.  VBA doesn't use parens around subroutine calls that don't return a value, and [they actually cause evaluation of the default property rather than passing the object itself](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/).

Comment: @cxw Thanks a lot! It works! I come from c# background and I'm used to have parenthesis on methods calls. If you write this comment as answer, I will vote it as the right answer.

Comment: @Oscar done :) .  Please also consider upvoting QHarr's since it has the code, though not the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs (i.e., raises the "Not implemented" message) on my test system with these two changes:

1. In your button-click module, remove the parentheses around `New TiendaRepository`.

   ```
   Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
       Dim bl As BlSecurity
       Set bl = New BlSecurity
       bl.Init New TiendaRepository  ' <=== here
       bl.Login txtUsuario.Value
   End Sub
   ```

   This is because VBA doesn't use parentheses when calling subroutines and not collecting a return value.  If you add the parentheses, [they actually cause evaluation of the default property](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/).  Therefore, instead of passing the `New TiendaRepository` object to `bl.Init`, you are passing whatever VBA thinks the default value is.

   Note that the VBA editor put a space before the opening parenthesis in your code.  That's a visual clue that it's not doing what you might expect coming from languages that always use parens on calls.
2. In `BlSecurity.Init`, add a `Set`:

   ```
   Public Sub Init(ptiendaRepo As ITiendaRepository)
       Set tiendaRepo = ptiendaRepo
   End Sub
   ```

   That is because you always (as far as I know) need `Set` when you are assigning objects (internally, references to objects).

If you want to use parentheses around method calls (not function calls) in VBA, you use the `Call` keyword.  That is,

```
Call bl.Init(New TiendaRepository)
```

is the same as

```
bl.Init New TiendaRepository
```

This is true regardless of the number of parameters — `Call foo(a,b,c)` is the same as `foo a, b, c`.

Comment: @QHarr Fair enough :) .  We were working in parallel.

Comment: Though I am up for seeing an improvement on mine as I am pretty naff at classes.

Comment: Thanks! Your tips about parenthesis usage and space before the opening parenthesis are very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

1) Note of set keyword

2) Removal of () in call

3) BlSecurity must also implement ITiendaRepository_CheckIfCodeExists

BlSecurity

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Implements iTiendaRepository

Private tiendaRepo As iTiendaRepository

Public Sub Init(ptiendaRepo As iTiendaRepository)
   Set tiendaRepo = ptiendaRepo     '*1
End Sub

Public Sub Login(code As String)
    If tiendaRepo.CheckIfCodeExists(code) = "" Then
       Err.Raise Number:=CustomErrors.CenterCodeNotExisting
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set tiendaRepo = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function ITiendaRepository_CheckIfCodeExists(ByVal code As String) As String '*3
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, "CheckCode", "Not implemented"
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Module

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim bl As BlSecurity
    Set bl = New BlSecurity
    bl.Init New TiendaRepository '*2
    bl.Login txtUsuario.Value '<=== Not sure where declare and should remove () 
End Sub
```

Though I am unsure where you have declared txtUsuario